# Video HLS with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I've converted .MOV video using this command line :

```
ffmpeg -re -i 123.mov -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list 123.m3u8 \-segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 3 123%03d.ts
```

output :

```
    ffmpeg version N-81872-gbe1d324 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
      libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
      libavcodec     57. 60.101 / 57. 60.101
      libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
      libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
      libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
      libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
      libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '123.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
      Duration: 00:00:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1210 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 540x960, 1088 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : H.264
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 114 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Output #0, segment, to '123%03d.ts':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        encoder         : Lavf57.51.102
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 540x960, q=2-31, 1088 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 600 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : H.264
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : Lavc57.60.101 mp2
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp2 (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=    1 fps=1.0 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.996x   
 frame=   32 fps= 16 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.987x   
 frame=   47 fps= 19 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.52 bitrate=N/A speed=0.996x   
 frame=   63 fps= 21 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.01 bitrate=N/A speed=0.993x   
  frame=   77 fps= 22 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.54 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
 frame=   93 fps= 23 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.03 bitrate=N/A speed=0.995x   
  frame=  108 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
 frame=  123 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.05 bitrate=N/A speed=0.997x   
  frame=  139 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.55 bitrate=N/A speed=0.996x   
 frame=  154 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.994x   
  frame=  169 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.57 bitrate=N/A speed=0.997x   
  frame=  184 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.09 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
  frame=  199 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
  frame=  230 fps= 27 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.58 bitrate=N/A speed=0.995x   
  frame=  261 fps= 27 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.60 bitrate=N/A speed=0.996x   
  frame=  275 fps= 27 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
  frame=  306 fps= 27 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.14 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
  frame=  337 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.13 bitrate=N/A speed=0.997x   
  frame=  352 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.65 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
  frame=  367 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.15 bitrate=N/A speed=0.997x   
  frame=  382 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.67 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
  frame=  412 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.69 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
  frame=  428 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.19 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
  frame=  443 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.68 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
  frame=  473 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:16.70 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
  frame=  488 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:17.22 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
  frame=  519 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:18.24 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
  frame=  550 fps= 29 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=N/A speed=0.998x   
  frame=  565 fps= 29 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:19.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x   
  frame=  601 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:20.02 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x    
    video:2663kB audio:939kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

The final video is available [here](http://www.appscenes.fr/videos/123.m3u8), i'm able to read it from Safari on Mac OS, but it doesn't work on iOS using AVPlayer or Safari.

I also tried to play it using [this sample code provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html), however i get the following error : 
"The decoder required for this media cannot be found"

Any help is appreciated

---

**edit 1**

I've edit the command line, and now i'm able to play the video using AVPlayer, but there is no sound...

```
ffmpeg -i 123.mov -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 64k -c:v h264 -preset slow -map 0 -an -flags -global_header -f hls -hls_time 2 123%03d.ts
```

OUTPUT :

```
    ffmpeg version N-81883-gbeb877b Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 60.101 / 57. 60.101
  libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '123.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1210 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 540x960, 1088 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 114 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (123%03d.ts) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Codec AVOption profile () specified for output file #0 (123%03d.ts) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] profile High, level 3.1
Output #0, hls, to '123%03d.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf57.51.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 540x960, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-09-26T19:34:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.60.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  600 fps= 79 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:19.90 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=0 speed=2.63x    
video:3542kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] frame I:18    Avg QP:21.70  size: 13958
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] frame P:326   Avg QP:23.78  size:  7702
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] frame B:256   Avg QP:24.83  size:  3380
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] consecutive B-frames: 26.8% 46.0%  8.5% 18.7%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] mb I  I16..4: 21.5% 71.7%  6.9%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] mb P  I16..4: 14.9% 29.6%  1.5%  P16..4: 32.2%  5.4%  2.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:14.1%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] mb B  I16..4:  3.0%  4.4%  0.3%  B16..8: 37.9%  4.5%  0.4%  direct: 5.0%  skip:44.6%  L0:50.0% L1:47.1% BI: 2.9%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] 8x8 transform intra:64.3% inter:82.5%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] direct mvs  spatial:97.7% temporal:2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 30.0% 44.4% 4.9% inter: 10.1% 20.7% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 29% 33% 13% 26%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 24% 18%  4%  5%  6%  8%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 35% 11%  4%  6%  5%  9%  4%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 36% 29% 23% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.9% UV:0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] ref P L0: 80.5%  9.7%  6.1%  2.0%  1.3%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] ref B L0: 92.2%  5.5%  2.0%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] ref B L1: 99.0%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x14ca8a0] kb/s:1450.98
```

Comment: You're using `-vcodec copy`, but you don't show what the actual format is. As with most `ffmpeg` questions you need to show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: i've edited the post with the output from my command